# $\mathbb{Z}$ has cohomological dimension one

Tags: abstract-algebra, homological-algebra

My lecture notes state the following with no further explanation:

> If $R=\mathbb{Z}$, then every R-module admits a resolution of length 1. This implies that $Tor_i^{\mathbb{Z}}$ and $Ext_{\mathbb{Z}}^{i}$ vanishes as soon as $i>1$. This property is called '$\mathbb{Z}$ has cohomological dimension one'.

So I am guessing that that *"admits a resolution of length 1"* here is meant to mean that *"admits both an injective and a projective resolution of length 1"*. Or is my guess wrong? Also, is this some triviality (I couldn't show it!) or is less obvious? If it's not too difficult, I'd be interested in a formal proof as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You only need projective resolutions; for Ext you resolve the first argument, not the second. If $A$ is an abelian group, first consider any surjection $f : \bigoplus_I \mathbb{Z} \to A$ from a free abelian group to $A$. The kernel of this surjection is another free abelian group $\bigoplus_J \mathbb{Z}$, because subgroups of free abelian groups are free abelian. So we have a resolution

$$0 \to \bigoplus_J \mathbb{Z} \to \bigoplus_I \mathbb{Z} \to A \to 0.$$

Comment: It's also true, both because injective abelian groups are exactly the divisible groups, so closed under quotient, and as a consequence of the ext statement, that short injective resolutions exist.